# Can I turn off my computer when running jupyter notebook on AWS EC2?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook

I'm running Jupyter Notebook on an EC2 instance.
I'm wondering if I set my computer to sleep or turn it off, will it interrupt the running?

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use terminal multiplexer for long running processes. You just kick start the `tmux` session before initiate your command and run your command inside tmux. It will prevent your job to stop even your session gets disconnected.

[for more info](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki)